# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'singlet'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scanpy

I have this data in csv file which a column has string value (`prediction` column). How do I rectify the `ValueError` so that I can read the file?'[image]

Code I attempted:

```
adata['prediction'].replace('singlet').astype(float)
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert a string of chars into a float?

Comment: Please make this a small, working example. You only need the prediction column and only a few values in it. And btw, are there other values in this column besides "singlet"? If so, are they always the string values of floats.

Comment: See what `adata['prediction'].replace('singlet')` returns. You'll be better off with `replace("singlet", "0")`

Comment: @tdelaney 
`adata['prediction'].replace('singlet',0,inplace=True)`
`adata['doublet'].replace('singlet',0,inplace=True)` replaced all the 'singlet' into zeros and it didn't give me any error afterwards. Thank you for your help!